# ¿Cómo crear una gráfica de cascada ("waterfall chart") con ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

El sistema de generación de gráficos de R `ggplot2` es sorprendentemente versátil, pero no he encontrado la forma de generar una gráfica de cascada (*waterfall chart*) similar a éste:

[image: Waterfall chart]

¿Cómo puedo, utilizando `ggplot2`, generar este tipo de gráfico?

---

Datos de ejemplo (similares a los de la gráfica mostrada:

```
df <- data.frame(
  montos = c(420, 210, -170, -140),
  row.names = c('Ingresos', 'Otros ingresos', 'Costos fijos', 'Costos variables')
)
df
##                  montos
## Ingresos            420
## Otros ingresos      210
## Costos fijos       -170
## Costos variables   -140
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Se necesitan algunos pasos previos para poder generar esa gráfica, así que vamos a tratar de generarla a la vez que explico cada paso.

**1. Inicializar los datos**

Tal como lo pusiste en la pregunta, la inicialización sería algo así (sólo he cambiado `row.names` por `nombres` para poner ambas en español) y he añadido el saldo inicial y el final:

```
df <- data.frame(
  montos = c(100, 320, 210, -170, -140, 320),
  nombres = c('Saldo Inicial', 'Ingresos', 'Otros ingresos', 'Costos fijos', 'Costos variables', 'Saldo Final')
)
```

Comprobamos que todo está como deseamos:

```
df

## nombres           montos
## Saldo Inicial       100
## Ingresos            320
## Otros ingresos      210
## Costos fijos       -170
## Costos variables   -140
## Saldo Final         320
```

**2. Preservar el orden**

Para preservar el orden de los datos debemos convertir los `nombres` al tipo de dato `factor`.

```
df$desc <- factor(df$nombres, levels = df$nombres)
```

**3. Agregar columnas**

Agregamos una columna `id` y una `tipo`

```
df$id <- seq_along(df$montos)
df$tipo <- ifelse(df$montos > 0, "in", "out") # Si es positivo será un ingreso y en caso contrario será un egreso
df[df$nombres %in% c("Saldo Inicial", "Saldo Final"), "tipo"] <- "net" # Esto es para el balance inicial y final
```

Luego agregamos dos columnas, `start` y `end`, esto para poner el valor inicial y final del monto en cada paso:

```
df$end <- cumsum(df$montos)
df$end <- c(head(df$end, -1), 0)
df$start <- c(0, head(df$end, -1))
```

Si no me he equivocado, tu `df` debería lucir así:

```
## id  tipo  nombres           start end  montos
## 1   net   Saldo Inicial     0     100  100
## 2   in    Ingresos          100   420  320
## 3   in    Otros ingresos    420   630  210
## 4   out   Costos fijos      630   460 -170
## 5   out   Costos variables  460   320 -140
## 6   net   Saldo Final       320   0    320
```

**4. Generar la gráfica**

Ahora sí, para generar la gráfica hacemos lo siguiente:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(nombres, fill = tipo)) + geom_rect(aes(x = nombres,
       xmin = id - 0.45, xmax = id + 0.45, ymin = end,
       ymax = start))
```

**5. Resultado**

[image: Resultado]
Básicamente eso sería todo. Se le pueden hacer algunas mejoras dependiendo de lo que te interese en la gráfica resultado.

**Puedes ver el [código completo en este demo](http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=pN8RVqMI&version=1).**

**6. Extras**

Esto reemplaza los espacios por saltos de línea para que sean más legibles los títulos.

```
strwr <- function(str) gsub(" ", "\n", str)
(p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(fill = tipo)) + geom_rect(aes(x = nombres,
    xmin = id - 0.45, xmax = id + 0.45, ymin = end,
    ymax = start)) + 
    scale_x_discrete("", breaks = levels(df$nombres),
    labels = strwr(levels(df$nombres))) +
    theme(legend.position = "none")
)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 6):

Como alternativa puedes usar el paquete [waterfall](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/waterfall/docs/waterfallchart) implementado con lattice ([sitio del autor](https://jameshoward.us/2010/05/23/waterfall-charts-in-r/)).

Ejemplo:

```
library(latticeExtra)
library(waterfall)

df <- data.frame(
  montos = c(420, 210, -170, -140),
  names = c('Ingresos', 'Otros ingresos', 'Costos fijos', 'Costos variables')
)
df$names <- factor(df$names, levels=unique(df$names))
df

##                  montos
## Ingresos            420
## Otros ingresos      210
## Costos fijos       -170
## Costos variables   -140

waterfallchart(montos ~ names, data=df, main="Waterfall graph")
```

Resultado en: [R-Fiddle](http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=MGu0TpCS&version=2)

Comment: ¡Wow! Impresionantemente simple

Comment: Interesante librería, no la conocía.